# Prob. 8(c) in Exercises after Sec. 17 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Does equality hold? Or does either inclusion hold?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space; let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of $X$. Then what is the relation between the closure $\overline{A \setminus B}$ in $X$ of the set $A \setminus B$ and the difference $\overline{A} \setminus \overline{B}$ between the closures of $A$ and $B$?

Does either of $\overline{A \setminus B} \subset \overline{A} \setminus \overline{B}$ or $\overline{A \setminus B} \supset \overline{A} \setminus \overline{B}$ hold?

And if so, then what is (are) the necessary and / or sufficient condition(s), if any, for the equality to hold as well?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this? Can you prove one of the inclusions? Have you looked at possible counterexamples?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that $\overline{A\setminus{B}} = \overline{A}\setminus{B^\circ}$ where $B^\circ$ denotes the interior of $B$. Indeed, $A\setminus{B}$ is contained in the right hand side which is closed being the intersection of $\overline{A}$ and $X\setminus{B^\circ}$, so $\overline{A\setminus{B}} \subseteq \overline{A}\setminus{B^\circ}$. Conversely if $x \in \overline{A}\setminus{B^\circ}$ and $U$ is any neighbourhood of $x$, then $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $U \not\subseteq B$, hence $U \cap (A\setminus{B}) \neq \emptyset$, thus $x \in \overline{A \setminus{B}}$.

From this we see that we always have $\overline{A\setminus{B}} \supseteq \overline{A}\setminus{\overline{B}}$ but in general this will be a strict inclusion. For equality you would have to have $\overline{A} \cap B^\circ = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$, that is, $\overline{A} \cap B$ would have to be clopen in $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's see if this is possible: $\overline{A \setminus B} \subset \overline{A} \setminus \overline{B}$.

As a counterexample think of two intersecting open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

If you take $x\in$$\partial$$B$$\cap$$A$. For every neighbourhood of $x$, $U_x$$\cap$ ${A\setminus B}$$\neq$$\emptyset$.

So $x\in$$\overline{A \setminus B}$ but clearly $x\in$$\overline{B}$.

In the other situation:

$x\in$$\overline{A} \setminus \overline{B}$ then for every neighbourhood of $x$, $U_x$ $\cap$  $A$$\neq$ $\emptyset$ but $\exists$ $V_{x}$ such that $V_{x}$$\cap$  $B$$=$ $\emptyset$

Let's check $U_x$$\cap$ ${A\setminus B}$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$.

Suppose $\exists$ $V_{x}$ such that  $V_x$$\cap$ ${A\setminus B}$ $=$$\emptyset$ then $V_{x}$$\subset$ $A\cap$$B$ $\implies$ $x\in$$B$  (contradiction)